# update YAML file using YQ in GitlabCI

Tags: gitlab-ci, jq, yq

So basically, I have this command that runs in Gitlab CI to update a field in YAML configuration before packaging and pushing a Helm chart.

```
yq -i -y ".pod.image.imageTag="${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"" deployment/values.yaml
```

values.yaml

```
pod:
  image:
    repository: my.private.repo/my-project
    imageTag: 'latest'
  nodegroupName: "nessie-nodegroup"
```

But I keep getting this error.

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?)
.pod.image.imageTag=4c0118bf
```

The variable is actually read but it looks like I'm doing something wrong in the yq command.
Any ideas where that error is coming from ? Trying with only one quote doesn't read the environment variable obviously. I already tried it.

Update:

Trying with :

```
yq -i -y '.pod.image.imageTag="${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"' deployment/values.yaml
```

and

```
yq -i -y .pod.image.imageTag="${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" deployment/values.yaml
```

didn't work either.

Comment: You likely need to escape the inner quotes, like this:

yq -i -y ".pod.image.imageTag=\"${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}\"" deployment/values.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `-y` option I assume you are using the [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info).

Use jq's `--arg` option to introduce values from shell:

```bash
yq -i -y --arg tag "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" '.pod.image.imageTag=$tag' deployment/values.yaml
```

Comment: That actually workd. Thank you so much for the quick and efficient answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Since the Q has been tagged `jq`, it might be worth mentioning that the Go implementation of jq supports YAML, so e.g.:

```
CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=foo
gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output --arg tag "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" '
  .pod.image.imageTag=$tag
' values.yaml
```

produces

```
pod:
  image:
    imageTag: foo
    repository: my.private.repo/my-project
  nodegroupName: nessie-nodegroup
```

Notice, though, that gojq sorts the keys.